# Mount a share on a Mac using a login hook

Tags: macos, mac, script, mount

I have a script that mounts a Samba share to a folder on the desktop, it runs no problem but when its setup as a LoginHook it doesn't mount the folder.

Does anyone have a working login hook that mounts a share that they can post? Or know any issues with mounting shares during login?

This is my Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
@domain="Lancaster"
@user=ARGV[0]
#@user=@user.gsub(/\n/,"")
@userfolder="/Users/" + @user.to_s
@smbshare="//#{@user}@hercules/everyone"
system("mkdir #{@userfolder}/Desktop/everyone")
system("mount_smbfs #{@smbshare} #{@userfolder}/Desktop/everyone | #{@userfolde$
system("
/usr/bin/osascript <<-EOF
        tell application \"System Events\"
                activate
                display dialog \"Welcome to the #{@domain} domain #{@user}\n\nY$
        end tell
EOF
")
```

Comment: What script do you have now?

Comment: How did you set up the LoginHook ?

Comment: You might want to follow up up on your questions and respond to the answers you get.

Comment: @Daniel I am not comfortable closing this question. It is has a good answer, and although the OP has given up, this question has had a 1000+ views since it has been asking, so it's definitely drawing people from Google. Weighing that up, I'd rather keep it open. There is a few 100 odd abandoned questions that still provide value to Super User.

Comment: @Diago Thanks for the response. You might want to discuss this with @studiohack though.

Comment: @Daniel He has made a call on it, and I am not going to override him.

Comment: @Diago, see chat.

Answer (score 3):

## Overview:

Create a launchd agent (a bash script in this case) to mount us whatever shares we like every couple of minutes.  It is not perfect but it works.  This is for Samba shares, but you can modify it to do other types.

Made with help from Dave Nicoll's about sharing windows/x iTunes libraries.

I'm using my laptop's wireless card to determine if I am connected to my home SSID. You can of course use anything you'd like for conditional execution.

*If you're going to use SSID as a condition for mounting as I have you may find it benificial to alias the Airport utility that ships with OS X to your /usr/bin/. If not skip ahead to the next section.*

Open **Terminal** and run:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/sbin/airport
```

Remember the output of this:

```
airport -I | grep '.* SSID:' | sed 's/^.* SSID: //'
```

### The Script:

My conditionals check for

1. The share is not already mounted *(line 1-4)*
2. The SSID of our Airport card network is not null *(line 5-8)*
3. That our SSID must be equal to a pre-defined SSID, in my case "2600leagues" *(line 9)*

Open your favorite text editor and start a new file, I called mine MountShares.sh

```
if [ -d '/Users/kyle/Music/iTunes/Podcasts/' ]; then
        #echo Nothing to do, share is mounted
        exit
else 
    if [ -z `airport -I | grep '.* SSID:' | sed 's/^.* SSID: //'` ]; then
       #echo SSID is Null, we're not connected with the Airport to any Network.
        exit
    else 
        if [ `airport -I | grep '.* SSID:' | sed 's/^.* SSID: //'` == "2600leagues" ]; then
            #echo SSID is 2600leagues!
            /sbin/mount -o nodev,nosuid -t smbfs '//Kyle:NotmyPassword@192.168.1.5/media/Music' '/Users/kyle/Music/'
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Next we need to edit line 11 to represent your specific needs. You only need to edit the **bold** parts:

> /sbin/mount -o nodev,nosuid -t smbfs
>   **'//User:Password@ServerIP_or_Name/Share**'
>   '**/Where/You/Want/it_to_mount/**'

**Example:**

```
/sbin/mount -o nodev,nosuid -t smbfs '//Kyle:NotmyPassword@192.168.1.5/media/Music' '/Users/kyle/Music/'
```

Now that we have our edited mount command, try running it in **Terminal**.  If it is successful, your share should be available at the mount location. (in my example `/Users/kyle/Music/`)

Edit the *line 1* of the bash script to reflect a file or directory inside the mounted share.  If you are going to use the SSID as a condition as I have, you'll want to change *line 5* by replacing **2600leagues** with your SSID.

Save the bash script in a convenient location. (I use `~/Library/Scripts/NetworkMounts/MountShares.sh`)

You now need to make the bash script executable, we use **chmod** to do this.

In **Terminal**:

```
chmod 777 ~/Library/Scripts/NetworkMounts/MountShares.sh
```

If the network share is still mounted, make sure you unmount/eject it now. (**Finder** works)

Try executing the script via **Terminal**:

```
~/Library/Scripts/NetworkMounts/MountShares.sh
```

If all goes well your share should be mounted.  Now all that is left to do is make it so the script runs every so often.  Normally you would use **crontab** for this sort of thing, but 10.6 has deprecated it.  Apple would rather you use their **launchd** service.

### Making the **launchd** Agent

To help you make a launchd agent get [Lingon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/files/Lingon/2.1.1/Lingon-2.1.1.zip/download) from sourceforge.

1. Open Lingon
2. Create a new User Agent (My Agent)
3. Give it a name such as
   *com.kyle.MountShares*
4. Choose or type the path to the bash
   script
   `~/Library/Scripts/NetworkMounts/MountShares.sh`
5. Specify when you would like it to
   run. (I have *Run when it is loaded
   by the system* and *Run it every
   **10** minutes)
6. Save it
7. Exit Lingon

**That's it**

Let me know if this helps; I typed all this out as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I spent the better part of my Friday last week trying to figure this out too. As it turns out, the user logon name is now case sensitive. For example, in my AD users have a logon like "JSmith". 
Mounting a share with the username "jsmith" fails with "Broken pipe". Mounting with "JSmith" works as expected for me.

I'm using 10.5.8.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following script with success in the past but I haven't used or needed it for a while:

```
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/Folder
mount_smbfs //domain;USERNAME@server.example.com/Share /Users/username/Desktop/Folder
```

Comment: Looks to me that the folder is created every time the script is executed... is this the intention?

Comment: I've fixed the post to make the folder if it doesn't exist. Some operating systems (eg. Mac OS X) depending on how the volume is unmounted (eg. not using `umount`) will remove the folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a Login Hook you could bind the Mac client to your AD Domain. In the user's AD account you can set the home folder to be your SMB share and configure everything so that the folder mounts at login. Alternatively if this is a shared machine and it's not a `user` home folder, you could set machine preference to mount a share on the computer at startup. You get the added advantage of AD authentication for your users.

Comment: Already done, they use AD for authentication but the home folder dont get mounted. Id rather not redirect the home folder as that would mean having uncompressed video/audio flying around the network. Rather have them only copy what they want off the mac into thier domain documents